# The behaviour of unions in C

Tags: c

I am really dumb. Please help me out by explaining the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union x
{
    int a;
    char b;
    double c;
};

int main()
{
    union x x[3] = {{1}, {'a'}, {1.2}};
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%d , %d , %lf\n", x[i].a, x[i].b, x[i].c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Also please read a tutorial if you are not sure what code does and run a debugger.

Comment: @Rajesh: That is not a helpful comment. One who does not understand that the compiler does not match the type of an initializer to the member might make the same mistake for a struct as for a union. Even if they did not, knowing that a struct stores multiple objects while a union stores only one of several does not mean one would know that the compiler does not match the type of the initializer to the member to be initialized.

Comment: What I though was that the compiler was intelligent enough to match the data to its respective data type when there were not more than variable of the same type...You know, one of those , "optimization" things.

Comment: @harsh82: “Optimization” generally means making things perform better without changing their defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

think of a union as an allocated space in the memory (size of which is the largest element in the union) each union defined can be interpeted as either element of the union so you can look at that allocated memory as a different type

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm

taken from the link:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

union Data {
   int i;
   float f;
   char str[20];
};

int main( ) {

   union Data data;        

   data.i = 10;
   printf( "data.i : %d\n", data.i);

   data.f = 220.5;
   printf( "data.f : %f\n", data.f);

   strcpy( data.str, "C Programming");
   printf( "data.str : %s\n", data.str);

   return 0;
}
```

as you can see it has defined one union but it used three different times as a different type

---

EDIT:
by C99 when initalizing a `union` the first element is the one initialized hence the value `1.2` is casted to `1` where in the case of the `char` the casting works as expected

if you reorder the elements in your `union` you will get:

```
0 , 0 , 1.000000                                                                                                                                             
0 , 0 , 97.000000                                                                                                                                            
858993459 , 51 , 1.200000
```

for further explanation:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

> When initializing a struct, the first initializer in the list
>   initializes the first declared member (unless a designator is
>   specified) (since C99), and all subsequent initializers without
>   designators (since C99)initialize the struct members declared after
>   the one initialized by the previous expression.

---

as mentioned in other comments there is a lot of information on the issue and you should research it further, but i hope this gives you a starting point

Comment: Thank you. It does. I am fairly informed about the concepts of designated intializers. What I don't understand is how my code leads to 0.000... for the double output in the thrird line of the output.

Answer (score 0):

As per C99 standard, you can still initialize your union with one-liner using [designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) without losing your data:

```
union x x[3] = {{.a = 1}, {.b = 'a'}, {.c = 1.2}};
```

This will force compiler to use particular union's member, rather than type of first declared one (which is `int` in your case).

Output:

```
1, 1, 0.000000
97, 97, 0.000000
858993459, 51, 1.200000
```

[Proof](https://ideone.com/dqQnv6).

Comment: no , i understood the integer and character part when i saw the code but what's bugging me is the double output.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide an initial value for a union, the compiler assigns it to the first member of the union. So, given:

```
union x
{
    int a;
    char b;
    double c;
};
```

and:

```
union x x[3] = {{1}, {'a'}, {1.2}};
```

the compiler initializes `x[0].a` to `1`, `x[1].a` to `a`, and `x[2].a` to 1.2. The compiler does not use the types of the initial values to match them to union elements. It merely initializes the first member with the value you give it. If there is a difference in types, the compiler converts the value to the type of the first member. (If that is a legal conversion. Otherwise, the compiler should provide a warning or error message.)

To initialize specific members of the union, you can use designated initializers, in which you explicitly name the member of the union you want to initialize:

```
union x x[3] = { { .a = 1 }, { .b = 'a' }, { .c = 1.2 } };
```

Comment: was helpful. I still don't understand how the floating output's coming up.

Comment: @harsh82: Floating-point values are encoded in a special format. Printing the value of a floating-point member of a union after storing a value to a different member causes the implementation to reinterpret the bits of the latter member as if they encoded a floating-point value. In the encoding, small numbers such as 1 or 97 (for `a` in ASCII) encode very small floating-point values. They are so small that, when printed with `%lf`, they appear as zero. (Since `double` has more bytes than `char`, this also requires the extra bytes happen to be zero. Otherwise some other value could be printed.)